# ¿Como hacer que desde un script bash se añada un texto al final de un archivo y se guarde?

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy haciendo un Script en Bash y necesito que añada unas lineas de texto a un archivo que el usuario debe tener en una ruta concreta , necesito que añada el texto al final del archivo y que se guarden los cambios ¿Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir o concatenar contenido a un documento puedes utilizar el comando `>>`, es decir:

```
echo "hola mundo!" >> ruta/archivo
```

Añadirá el contenido que le concatenes al final del archivo respetando el contenido que tenga previamente.